# HashSet using custom hashCode

Tags: java, equals, hashset, hashcode

Could someone point me the right direction: I would like to have a custom `HashSet` without changing `hashCode()/equals()` methods.

Usage would be to have a Set of objects which must have different one attribute (or more).

So, for example, for this Class:

```java
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter @Setter
public class User{
    String name;
    String email;
    String age;
}
```

I would like to have `UserNameSet` which would allow to contain only users which have different name. I do not want to override the hashCode and equals method in User, because I still want to differentiate between users with same name but different email for example.

I would like to somehow **"override"** the `hashCode()/equals()` method just for this one `HashMap`.

**EDITED**

I have come up with this solution on first glance it works, could someone check it?

```java
package com.znamenacek.debtor.util;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class CustomizableHashSet<T> implements Set<T> {
    Function<T, Integer> customHashCode = Object::hashCode;
    HashSet<ClassWrapper> storage = new HashSet<>();

    public CustomizableHashSet(Function<T, Integer> customHashCode) {
        this.customHashCode = customHashCode;
    }

    public CustomizableHashSet() {}

    public CustomizableHashSet(Collection<? extends T> c, Function<T, Integer> customHashCode) {
        storage = new HashSet<>(c.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).toList());
        this.customHashCode = customHashCode;
    }

    public CustomizableHashSet(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        storage = new HashSet<>(c.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).toList());
    }

    public CustomizableHashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, Function<T, Integer> customHashCode) {
        storage = new HashSet<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
        this.customHashCode = customHashCode;
    }

    public CustomizableHashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        storage = new HashSet<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }

    public CustomizableHashSet(int initialCapacity, Function<T, Integer> customHashCode) {
        storage = new HashSet<>(initialCapacity);
        this.customHashCode = customHashCode;
    }

    public CustomizableHashSet(int initialCapacity) {
        storage = new HashSet<>(initialCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return storage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return storage.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet()).contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        return storage.add(new ClassWrapper(t));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        boolean returnValue;
        var storageContent = storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        returnValue = storageContent.remove(o);
        storage = storageContent.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        storage.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).spliterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T1> T1[] toArray(T1[] a) {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet()).toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean returnValue;
        var storageContent = storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        returnValue = storageContent.removeAll(c);
        storage = storageContent.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean returnValue;
        var storageContent = storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        returnValue = storageContent.containsAll(c);
        storage = storageContent.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return storage.addAll(c.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean returnValue;
        var storageContent = storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        returnValue = storageContent.retainAll(c);
        storage = storageContent.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet()).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public <T1> T1[] toArray(IntFunction<T1[]> generator) {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet()).toArray(generator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super T> filter) {
        boolean returnValue;
        var storageContent = storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        returnValue = storageContent.removeIf(filter);
        storage = storageContent.stream().map(ClassWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<T> stream() {
        return storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get);
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<T> parallelStream() {
        return storage.parallelStream().map(ClassWrapper::get);
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        storage.stream().map(ClassWrapper::get).forEach(action);
    }

    @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ClassWrapper{
        T object;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return customHashCode.apply(object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(this == obj) return true;

            if(obj == null) return false;

            return hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
        }

        public T get(){
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "" + hashCode() + " - " + object.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without overwriting hashCode, this won't work with a set. But you could e.g. use a `HashMap<String, User>`, mapping the names to full users, then get the values from that map.

Comment: Could just write another class that simply wraps a `User` instance and implements `equals` and `hashCode` as your want. Or write your own set implementation specifically for `User` (doesn't have to implement `Set`). Or use a `Map<String, User>` as a set. Or maybe some other idea I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Ok, thanks Slaw and tobias_k, both are useful replies, I was thinkin about something like that, but I wasn't sure if there isn't anything easier how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Slaw `UserDecorator` (with a an overridden `hashCode()` and `equals()`) sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be a `HashSet`, `TreeSet` has a constructor that takes a custom comparator.

Comment: @JakubZnamenáček If you want feedback on the code you wrote you should better ask over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Thank you, I did not know that something like that exists! Thanks

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Good suggestion. I posted [an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72482101/642706) using a `Comparator` with `TreeSet`. That does indeed seem to provide the behavior desired in this Question.

Comment: The `TreeSet` would be the better approach.  And it can check on any number of items using the custom Comparator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use `Comparator` with `TreeSet`

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478197/hashset-using-custom-hashcode/72482101#comment128035157_72478197) by Johannes Kuhn, you can get your desired behavior by using a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) (or `SortedSet`) or, in Java 21+,[`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html) ([JEP 431](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431)). **No need to invent your own class.**

Implementations of [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) such as [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) may offer a constructor taking a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) object. That `Comparator` is used for sorting the elements of the set.

To our point here in this Question, that `Comparator` is also used in deciding to admitting new distinct elements rather than using the elements’ own `Object#equals` method.

And since there is no hashing involved in a `TreeSet`, there is no concern about overriding `hashCode`.

We can easily define our `Comparator` implementation. For convenience, we can call [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) to make a comparator implementation. We define the comparator by passing a method reference for the getter method of your desired `name` field: `User :: name`.

You can add more criteria to your comparator by calling [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.function.Function)). I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

For brevity, let's define your `User` class as a [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). We simply declare the type and name of member fields. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record User( String name , String email , int age ) { }
```

Make some sample data.

```java
List < User > listOfUsers =
        List.of(
                new User( "Bob" , "bob@x.com" , 7 ) ,
                new User( "Alice" , "alice@x.com" , 42 ) ,
                new User( "Carol" , "carol@x.com" , 77 )
        );
```

Define our set, a `TreeSet`.

```java
NavigableSet < User > setOfUsers = new TreeSet <>( Comparator.comparing( User :: name )  );
```

Populate our set with 3 elements. Verify 3 elements by dumping to console.

```java
setOfUsers.addAll( listOfUsers );
System.out.println( setOfUsers.size() + " elements in setOfUsers = " + setOfUsers );
```

Now we try to add another user with the same name but different values in the other fields.

```java
setOfUsers.add( new User( "Alice" , "a@aol.com" , -666  ) );
```

By default, a `record` decides on equality by comparing each and every member field. So:

- If we have failed in our goal of using only `name` for comparison, we would get 4 elements in this set.
- If we have succeeded in using only `name`, then we should get 3 elements   after having blocked admission of this interloper.

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( setOfUsers.size() + " elements in setOfUsers = " + setOfUsers );
```

> 3 elements in setOfUsers = [User[name=Alice, email=alice@x.com, age=42], User[name=Bob, email=bob@x.com, age=7], User[name=Carol, email=carol@x.com, age=77]]
>
> 3 elements in setOfUsers = [User[name=Alice, email=alice@x.com, age=42], User[name=Bob, email=bob@x.com, age=7], User[name=Carol, email=carol@x.com, age=77]]

We see in those results (a) sorting of the elements by name, and (b) Blocking of the second `Alice`, with the original `Alice` remaining.

To see the alternate behavior, replace the `setOfUsers` definition with this:

```
Set < User > setOfUsers = new HashSet <>();
```

Running that edition of the code results in `setOfUsers.size()` being:

> 3 elements in setOfUsers = [User[name=Bob, email=bob@x.com, age=7], User[name=Carol, email=carol@x.com, age=77], User[name=Alice, email=alice@x.com, age=42]]
>
> 4 elements in setOfUsers = [User[name=Bob, email=bob@x.com, age=7], User[name=Carol, email=carol@x.com, age=77], User[name=Alice, email=alice@x.com, age=42], User[name=Alice, email=a@aol.com, age=-666]]

We see in those results (a) no particular sorting, and (b) the addition of a second "Alice", having increased the set from 3 elements to 4.

## Caveat

One possible downside to my solution here is that we are violating  the recommendation of the Javadoc of `TreeSet` to be “consistent with `equals`”, thereby violating the general contract of `Set`.

I am not sure if that issue is problematic or not — I do not have enough perspective to form a judgement.

Comment: Hi Basil, this is something I was looking for, are there some advantages and disadvantages against HashSet? I read that HashSet should be very fast in retrieving objects, but not so fast for iterating over them. How is it with ThreeSet, is there something I should know?

Comment: BTW, I am still surprised, that there isn't HashSet implementation in java which would accept custom hashCode and equals function in form of lambda expression.

Comment: @JakubZnamenáček The real purpose of `TreeSet` is to work with keys in sorted order. Performing the sort up front while utilizing the sort many times later is where a `NavigableSet` becomes efficient. We are bending that purpose to our own need here to work with `name` field.  So we are not gaining any benefit by the sort order being maintained. For further consideration of efficiency, I do not know — you'd have to examine the source code of the implementation in the OpenJDK codebase.

Comment: About the "not consistent with `equals`": Stuart Marks has given a great talk named [Collection Corner Cases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXdm5BzQ8mI) where he explains that (among other things).

Answer (score 4):

### Clean and Efficient

> I would like to have UserNameSet which would allow to contain only users which have different name

You can apply composition and create a class that would maintain a `Map` and delegate all calls to it.

The approach of encapsulating a collection and providing limited access to it is more flexible and less tedious than extending a collection, and also doesn't create a tight coupling.

Similar advice, and also examples of disadvantages that come with making your code dependent on the existing collection by extending it, you can find in the book *"Effective Java"* by *Joshua Bloch*, item *Favor composition over inheritance*.

That's how such a class might look like:

```
class UserNameSet {
    private Map<String, User> userByName = new HashMap<>();
    
    public User add(User user) {
        return userByName.put(user.getName(), user); // or `putIfAbsent()` if you want to retain the previously added user
    }
    
    public User remove(User user) {
        return userByName.remove(user.getName());
    }
    
    public boolean contains(User user) {
        return userByName.containsValue(user.getName());
    }
    
    public User remove(String name) {
        return userByName.remove(name);
    }
    
    public boolean contains(String name) {
        return userByName.containsKey(name);
    }
    
    // all other methods that are required
}
```

We can also make this class to be *generic* and capable of wrapping any object.

For that, we need to introduce an additional argument - a *function* that will be responsible for extracting the target property from the object.

```
class MyCustomSet<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> userByName = new HashMap<>();
    private Function<V, K> keyExtractor;
    
    public MyCustomSet(Function<V, K> keyExtractor) {
        this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
    }
    
    public V add(V user) {
        return userByName.put(keyExtractor.apply(user), user); // or `putIfAbsent()` if you want to retain the previously added user
    }
    
    public V remove(V user) {
        return userByName.remove(keyExtractor.apply(user));
    }
    
    public boolean contains(V user) {
        return userByName.containsValue(user);
    }
    
    public V removeByKey(K name) {
        return userByName.remove(name);
    }
    
    public boolean containsKey(K name) {
        return userByName.containsKey(name);
    }
    
    // all other methods that are required
}
```

And that's how it would be instantiated in the client code:

```
MyCustomSet<String, User> uniqueNameUsers = new MyCustomSet<>(User::getName);
```

### Concise and Simple

The approach of utilizing sorted collections like [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#method-summary) described in the [*Basil's Bourque answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72482101/17949945) can be used for a **relatively small** number of objects.

It's important to emphasize that storing the data in sorted collections has a cost. The larger they become, the slower they operate. `TreeSet` is backed by the [*Red-black tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) and most of the actions like basic `add()`, `remove()` and `contains()` operations require **O(n)** time, apart from the edge-cases when we deal with the *lowest/highest key*.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252956/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-ivanchenko-hashset-using-custom-hashcode); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

commons-collections already provides an [Equator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/Equator.html) interface to do what you suggest:

```
public interface Equator<T> {
    boolean equate(T o1, T o2);
    int hash(T o);
}
```

However direct support for creating collections based on an equator is limited. There are a few operations involving an equator available in [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html).

However you could leverage [Transformer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/Transformer.html) to wrap your desired objects into ones that use an equator and then use all the support commons-collections provides for transformers. For example using [SetUtils.transformedSet](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/SetUtils.html#transformedSet-java.util.Set-org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer-):

```
class EquatorWrapper<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final T wrapped;
    private final Equator<T> equator;

    public EquatorWrapper(Class<T> clazz, T wrapped, Equator<T> equator) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.equator = equator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
            return equator.equate(wrapped, clazz.cast(obj));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return equator.hash(wrapped);
    }
}

class EquatorTransformer<T> implements Transformer<T, Object> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Equator<T> equator;

    public EquatorTransformer(Class<T> clazz, Equator<T> equator) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.equator = equator;
    }
        
    @Override
    public Object transform(T input) {
        return new EquatorWrapper<>(clazz, input, equator);
    }
}

SetUtils.transformedSet(someSet, EquatorTransformer.of(someEquator, SomeClazz.clazz));
```